# Sorting issue one character and number with same string along with date logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

A holiday movie that is entertaining to all audiences of all backgrounds. It will stand the test of time to promote an era that holds itself to values of diversity. Diversity in experience that can unite all people and end hate in a hostile culture filled with echo chambers and Twitter mobs. A movie that can introduce open conversations entering the new decade. This movie will be tremendous.

Comment: is that right, that `priority_level` has a following space?

Comment: Yes @NinaScholz

Comment: are there other values possible?

Comment: @NinaScholz Like? Values?

Comment: it's not my data. do you have other values then the above for `priority_level`?

Comment: @NinaScholz no it will be single character values only

Comment: alphabets and numbers need to be lexicographically sorted or you just need alphabets then numbers?

Comment: @AZ_ I want Alphabets first then numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by priority_level first and then sort by the check if `priority_level` starts with a number and by `priority_date`.

```js
const
    hasNumber = s => /^\d+/.test(s),
    input = [{ priority_level: 'P ', priority_date: '1980-02-08T00:00:00.000Z' }, { priority_level: '1 ', priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z' }, { priority_level: 'C ', priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z' }, { priority_level: '5 ', priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z' }, { priority_level: '1 ', priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z' }, { priority_level: '1 ', priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z' }],
    result = [...input
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.priority_level, [...(m.get(o.priority_level) || []), o]), new Map)
        .values()
    ].flat();

result.sort((a, b) =>
    hasNumber(a.priority_level) - hasNumber(b.priority_level) ||
    a.priority_date > b.priority_date || -(a.priority_date < b.priority_date)
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With lodash

```js
const
    hasNumber = s => /^\d+/.test(s),
    input = [{ priority_level: 'P ', priority_date: '1980-02-08T00:00:00.000Z' }, { priority_level: '1 ', priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z' }, { priority_level: 'C ', priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z' }, { priority_level: '5 ', priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z' }, { priority_level: '1 ', priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z' }, { priority_level: '1 ', priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z' }],
    result = _(input)
        .groupBy('priority_level')
        .map(array => array)
        .flatten()
        .sortBy([
            o => hasNumber(o.priority_level),
            'priority_date'
        ])
        .values();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want result like C,P,1,1,5

for same like 1,1 it should be in ascending(2004,2005) order

Comment: are the numbers sorted? what about the letters should the be grouped as well?

Comment: Yes I want alphabets on top and then numbers, and if there's two same numbers than for those two sort by dates in ascending order

Comment: Can you use lodash?

Comment: actually i find out, what you want. i understand, that letters should come first, but by using a sorting approach you need a differens which one comes first nd the second. you can not group without have a relation with the order. if you need a grpouping of **only**  numbers, then fine, but this does not work with sorting alone. if you like to group **same** letters, you could do as well, but not with sorting alone.

Comment: Can you help me with this? I am bit new to certain things like this... It would be great if you can help me achieveing the right output

Comment: With same thing with this as input `[
        { priority_level: 'P ', priority_date: '1980-02-08T00:00:00.000Z' },
        { priority_level: '1 ', priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z' },
        { priority_level: 'C ', priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z' },
        { priority_level: '5 ', priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z' },
        { priority_level: '1 ', priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z' },
        { priority_level: '1 ', priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z' }
    ]` it shows P,1,1,5,1

Comment: With same number and same date it shows same level at last

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const input = [{
priority_level: 'P ',
comments: '',
withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
condition: '',
_id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d44',
company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9e0049',
priority_date: '1980-02-08T00:00:00.000Z',
registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4b',
sequence: 6835,
waiver_request: false,
waiver_granted: false,
waiver_letter_date: null,
letter_date: null,
waiver_sent: null,
no_extention_letter: false,
mpaa_extention_granted: false
},
{
priority_level: '1 ',
comments: '',
withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
condition: '',
_id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d43',
company: '5db00a145399ab5cad9e0096',
priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z',
registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
sequence: 13505,
waiver_request: false,
waiver_granted: false,
waiver_letter_date: null,
letter_date: null,
waiver_sent: null,
no_extention_letter: false,
mpaa_extention_granted: false
},
{
priority_level: 'C ',
comments: '',
withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
condition: '',
_id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d42',
company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5c',
priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z',
registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
sequence: 13506,
waiver_request: false,
waiver_granted: false,
waiver_letter_date: null,
letter_date: null,
waiver_sent: null,
no_extention_letter: false,
mpaa_extention_granted: false
},
{
priority_level: '5 ',
comments: '',
withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
condition: '',
_id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d41',
company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5a',
priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z',
registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
sequence: 13508,
waiver_request: false,
waiver_granted: false,
waiver_letter_date: null,
letter_date: null,
waiver_sent: null,
no_extention_letter: false,
mpaa_extention_granted: false
},

{
priority_level: '1 ',
comments: '',
withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
condition: '',
_id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d41',
company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5a',
priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z',
registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
sequence: 13508,
waiver_request: false,
waiver_granted: false,
waiver_letter_date: null,
letter_date: null,
waiver_sent: null,
no_extention_letter: false,
mpaa_extention_granted: false
}]


const result = input.sort((a, b) => {
    const isIntegerA = Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(a.priority_level));
    const isIntegerB = Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(b.priority_level));
    if (a.priority_level < b.priority_level) {
        if (isIntegerA & !isIntegerB) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.priority_level > b.priority_level) {
        if (!isIntegerA & isIntegerB) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return Date.parse(a.priority_date) - Date.parse(b.priority_date)
});
console.log(result);
```

```
const result = input.sort((a, b) => {
const isIntegerA = Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(a.priority_level));
const isIntegerB = Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(b.priority_level));
if (a.priority_level < b.priority_level) {
    if (isIntegerA & !isIntegerB) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
if (a.priority_level > b.priority_level) {
    if (!isIntegerA & isIntegerB) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
return Date.parse(a.priority_date) - Date.parse(b.priority_date)});
```

Comment: With this after 10 it comes after 1,

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own sorting logic.

```js
   const input = [{
priority_level: 'P ',
comments: '',
withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
condition: '',
_id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d44',
company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9e0049',
priority_date: '1980-02-08T00:00:00.000Z',
registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4b',
sequence: 6835,
waiver_request: false,
waiver_granted: false,
waiver_letter_date: null,
letter_date: null,
waiver_sent: null,
no_extention_letter: false,
mpaa_extention_granted: false
},
{
priority_level: '1 ',
comments: '',
withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
condition: '',
_id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d43',
company: '5db00a145399ab5cad9e0096',
priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z',
registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
sequence: 13505,
waiver_request: false,
waiver_granted: false,
waiver_letter_date: null,
letter_date: null,
waiver_sent: null,
no_extention_letter: false,
mpaa_extention_granted: false
},
{
priority_level: 'C ',
comments: '',
withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
condition: '',
_id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d42',
company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5c',
priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z',
registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
sequence: 13506,
waiver_request: false,
waiver_granted: false,
waiver_letter_date: null,
letter_date: null,
waiver_sent: null,
no_extention_letter: false,
mpaa_extention_granted: false
},
{
priority_level: '5 ',
comments: '',
withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
condition: '',
_id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d41',
company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5a',
priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z',
registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
sequence: 13508,
waiver_request: false,
waiver_granted: false,
waiver_letter_date: null,
letter_date: null,
waiver_sent: null,
no_extention_letter: false,
mpaa_extention_granted: false
},

{
priority_level: '1 ',
comments: '',
withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
condition: '',
_id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d41',
company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5a',
priority_date: '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z',
registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
sequence: 13508,
waiver_request: false,
waiver_granted: false,
waiver_letter_date: null,
letter_date: null,
waiver_sent: null,
no_extention_letter: false,
mpaa_extention_granted: false
}]


input.sort((a, b) => {
 if (a.priority_level.trim().match(/[A-Z]/)) {
  if (b.priority_level.trim().match(/[A-Z]/)) {
   return new Date(a.priority_date) - new Date(b.priority_date);
  } return -1;
 }
 else if (b.priority_level.trim().match(/[A-Z]/)) {
  return 1;
 }
 return new Date(a.priority_date) - new Date(b.priority_date)  || (a.priority_level - b.priority_level)
})
console.log(input.map(e => e.priority_level + e.priority_date))
```

Comment: I want result like C,P,1,1,5

Comment: Both have the same dates, so it will be in the same order you have in your original array.

Comment: I want result like C,P,1,1,5

Comment: Both have the same dates, so it will be in the same order you have in your original array.

Comment: Nandani you mentioned in the Question like P, C,1,1,5 right?

Comment: for same like 1,1 it should be in ascending(2004,2005) order

Comment: I have asked in the comment `alphabets and numbers need to be lexicographically sorted or you just need alphabets then numbers`

Comment: @Nandani Updated the solution but you need to be sure about your requirements.